# How to identify whether file is corrupted in java

Tags: java, file

I have a requirement to upload the documents.
In this I dont want to upload corrupted files in to server.
Can some one please tell me how I can identify corrupted file in java

Comment: Answer your own question without "in java" first. How you identify whether a file is corrupted without Java?

Comment: The actual scenario is we have given a web application where user is allowed to upload documents, Now I want to restrict users to upload the corrupted files,means if user selects corrupted file to upload I have to give him a message that u hv selected corrupted file. So how I can identify a corrupted file using java

Comment: There is no such thing as "corrupted file" in general. There can be "two files differ" or "file is not in the expected format", the latter is not always easy to determine, especially for multimedia files.

Comment: What is the definition of "corrupted" in this case?

Answer (score 4):

You could get a MD5 or other checksum of the file and compare the values created on the client and server after the transfer though this would only tell you if the file was corrupted during transport and not that the original file is actually valid/correct for the intended use/type.

Files are just containers for bytes with some filesystem descriptors. How they are read and used by applications is specific to each and every file format. *If* you wanted to validate the contents of files prior to upload as actually valid for use by some application or another you will either need to implement (or find) code to evaluate every file you want to support in a different way according to the requirements for that type or perhaps try to read/load/use the file in some sand-boxed application instance beforehand (sand-boxed as invalid files may break things if really invalid or potentially malicious).

Comment: before transfer I want to know whether user is trying to upload corrupted file

Comment: That's a whole different ballgame. You will need to check for appropriate and correct file headers, content and more. What exactly depends entirely on what exact file types you are talking about. It will be a different solution for every type.

Comment: One method that could work is attempt to load and read the file in the background first. If there are any exceptions then the file "may" be corrupt. But again, you'll have to handle every type differently. There isn't a catch-all solution. What types are you trying to test?

Comment: Since I have given upload functionality to users, they can upload any file types, this we cant restrict. It would be very difficult if I have to write for every file types that is available in real world

Comment: You could perhaps write a few tests for the common file types being uploaded but as you say; it's unrealistic to test every file type. You will have to accept the limitations or rework your design and restrict users to files that you do write tests for.